# gzip functions in python2 but python3 doesn't recognize zlib

Tags: python3, gzip, zlib

I have python2 by default and I use python3 instlled via apt-get, I import gzip in python2 without problem, but in python3 don't recognize zlib. I am a newbie in linux and don't have ideia what to do.

Updating

```
$readlink -f $(which python3)
/usr/local/bin/python3.5

$apt-cache policy libpython3-stdlib
libpython3-stdlib:
  Installed: 3.4.0-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 3.4.0-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 3.4.0-0ubuntu2 0
        500 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? python3 is normally installed by default - what version of python3 did you install exactly (`python3 --version`) and did you use a PPA to do so?

Comment: ubuntu 14.04 lts with gnome.

Comment: python3.5 via apt-get

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the outputs of commands `readlink -f $(which python3)` and `apt-cache policy libpython3-stdlib`